# Error with JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, object

The code only processes the last string of the object and then proceeds based off of that one and doesn't display a child's name even if their birthday does match today's date when that child's string of data is not the last one entered into the object. I need some advice or help in how to make the javascript find each person whose birthday matches the date and display them instead of just looking at the last child's data

```
var studentProfile = [];
var index=0;

function saveProfile()
{ 
studentProfile[index] = {
firstName: document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value,
surname: document.getElementById("txtSurname").value,
birthday: document.getElementById("txtBirthday").value,
contactInfomation: document.getElementById("txtContactInfomation").value,
medicalInformation: document.getElementById("txtMedicalInformation").value,
} 
index = index + 1;
localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(studentProfile));
}

function displayProfile()
{
for (var i = 0; i<studentProfile.length; i++) { 
alert("The Student's Name is " + studentProfile[i].firstName + " " + studentProfile[i].surname + "."); 
alert("The Student's Birthday is " + studentProfile[i].birthday + "."); 
alert("The Student's Contact Information is: " + studentProfile[i].contactInfomation + "."); 
alert("The Student's Medical Information is: " + studentProfile[i].medicalInformation) + "."; 
}
}

function clearData() 
{
 document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value = "";
 document.getElementById("txtSurname").value = "";
 document.getElementById("txtBirthday").value = "";
 document.getElementById("txtContactInfomation").value = "";
 document.getElementById("txtMedicalInformation").value = "";
}


function birthday()
{

//state all the variables for the program and convert the JSON string from the register js back into an object
var studentProfile = new Object();
var studentBirthday;
var bdayMonth, bdayDay;
var birthDate = new Date();
var today = new Date();
var todayMonth;
var todayDay;
studentProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));

// this variable is for the birthday picture to disappear if there are no birthdays, its used later on in the code
var BirthdayBorder = document.getElementById("BirthdayBorder");

// this variable is for the text to change position if there are no birthdays, its used later on in the code
var txtbirthday = document.getElementById("txtContainer");

//I had an alert here to see if the javascript was accurately able to convert the string back into an object and after this is the actual programs code
for (var i = 0; i < studentProfile.length; i++) 
{

    //here is where the variables regarding the date were specified and extracted from the object that was converted
    bdayMonth = studentProfile[i].birthday.substring(0,2);
    bdayDay = studentProfile[i].birthday.substring(3,5);
    todayMonth = today.getMonth()+1;
    todayDay = today.getDate();

    //this is where the comparison part of the code starts, basically the birthday entered by the user is compared with today's date
    if ((bdayDay == todayDay) && (bdayMonth == todayMonth)) 
    {

    //if the dates are equal to one another then the student's firstname is determined and displayed as an output in the html
        document.getElementById("birthdays").innerHTML = studentProfile[i].firstName;
        BirthdayBorder.style.opacity = "100";
        BirthdayBorder.style.marginTop = "0px";
        txtbirthday.style.marginTop = "144px";
    }
    else
    {
    //the program has determined that there are no birthdays today and will display the text instead of a student's name
        document.getElementById("birthdays").innerHTML = "No Birthdays Today! ;)";

        //this is the styling part for the birthday border to be transparent and moved to a place where it isn't affecting the website's margins and the text is moved to look better than being in empty space
        BirthdayBorder.style.opacity = "0";
        BirthdayBorder.style.marginTop = "-1000px";
        txtbirthday.style.marginTop = "-50px";
    }
}
}
```

okay here is the requested other information

html:
    
    
    
        
        The Plan

```
    <div id="Titlecont">
        <div id="Picture">
            <img src="LogoPicture.png" width=60 height=60>
        </div>


        <div id="Title">
            <h1>Little Hands Daycare</h1>
        </div>


        <div id="Motto">
            <p> "It takes a village to raise a child" </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="Button">
        <a href="Computer SciencesWE.html">
            <button type="button">
                Home
            </button> 
        </a>


        <a href="Timer.html">
            <button type="button">
                 Timer
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="About Us.html">
            <button type="button">
                About
            </button> 
        </a>

        <a href="Register.html">            
           <button type="button">
                Register
           </button> 
        </a>

        <a href="Schedule.html">
           <button type="button">
                Events
           </button>
        </a>


        <button type="button">
            Contact
        </button>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <!--This is where the daily schedule is coded-->
    <br>
    <div id="Schedule">
         <img src="Calender.jpg" width=800 height=540>
         <!--This is where the html displays the output of the js-->
         <div id="txtContainer">
            <p id="birthdays">
              .
            </p>
         </div>
         <div id="BirthdayBorder">
              <img src="Birthday Border.jpg" width=800 height=600>
         </div>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the requested portion of the javascript has been added to the top of the old code

Comment: Add the html and code of object/json for studentProfile you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop looping when you find a match. Otherwise, you'll process the non-matching items after it, which overwrites the changes you made.

```
var birthday_found = false;

for (var i = 0; i < studentProfile.length; i++) 
{
    //here is where the variables regarding the date were specified and extracted from the object that was converted
    bdayMonth = studentProfile[i].birthday.substring(0,2);
    bdayDay = studentProfile[i].birthday.substring(3,5);
    todayMonth = today.getMonth()+1;
    todayDay = today.getDate();

    //this is where the comparison part of the code starts, basically the birthday entered by the user is compared with today's date
    if ((bdayDay == todayDay) && (bdayMonth == todayMonth)) 
    {
        //if the dates are equal to one another then the student's firstname is determined and displayed as an output in the html
        document.getElementById("birthdays").innerHTML = studentProfile[i].firstName;
        BirthdayBorder.style.opacity = "100";
        BirthdayBorder.style.marginTop = "0px";
        txtbirthday.style.marginTop = "144px";
        birthday_found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!birthday_found)
{
    //the program has determined that there are no birthdays today and will display the text instead of a student's name
    document.getElementById("birthdays").innerHTML = "No Birthdays Today! ;)";

    //this is the styling part for the birthday border to be transparent and moved to a place where it isn't affecting the website's margins and the text is moved to look better than being in empty space
    BirthdayBorder.style.opacity = "0";
    BirthdayBorder.style.marginTop = "-1000px";
    txtbirthday.style.marginTop = "-50px";
}
```

Comment: ok, you helped me in giving me a general direction, but the code you gave doesn't work. Is that because of the two ifs?

Comment: One thing about this: it will only find one person with a matching birthday. You'll need to do some more work to handle multiple people with the same birthday.